# BTC not confirmed after 6+hrs

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

Can anyone help with why a simple transfer of BTC from BLOCKCHAIN to COINBASE wont confirm?  Fee paid and debited from my BLOCKCHAIN ac

2c4a037812e32a02ca12f4eb38577c11d65900872b5a795516c59f300afdbb9b

....and how I can rectify it!

Comment: Would be helpful if you provided the transaction ID.

Comment: Yupp, 40sat/B transaction fee is way too low. Check out the link mentioned by Nate Eldredge above this comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fee is 40 sat/b so it may take at least 48 blocks ( ~480 min) To confirm.